# Unity3D-how to change scale of avatar

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I downloaded a 3D model from the Asset Store. I changed the "Scale Factor" of the model to 0.25

[image]

I'm using this model in 2 different scenes and they need to be different sizes, one Scaled:0.25 and the other Scaled:0.40

How can I have the model in the other scene be scaled to 0.40?
Adjusting the scale of the transform of the model in the scene doesn't change the size of the model.

[image]

Please help. Thank you!

UPDATE: I'm learning more as I'm trying to figure this out. The original model is composed of Skinned Mesh Renderers (different costumes).
[image]

I decided to try something random, I made a 3D object (a sphere) which I could adjust the scale without issue. I then selected the mesh of the model for the MESH FILTER, and then I selected the material for the MESH RENDERER. I now have the model that I could scale without issue. Now the problem is, I made the gameObject a child of an empty gameObject and added an animator component to the parent gameObject, but it doesn't run any animations.
[image]

Made it a child of an empty gameObject with an animator component, but doesn't run any animations
[image]

Please advise.

Comment: **"Adjusting the scale of the transform of the model in the scene doesn't change the size of the model"** So what it do? Since the size of the model is not changed when changing its scale, what happens?

Comment: The model's position changes, so it would basically be as if I were changing the Transform.Position

Comment: Did you try putting this object as child to other empty gameObject and play with scale of the parent?

Comment: @JerrySwitalski When I do that, it only moves the model around as if we were changing the position. BUT, I just updated the post as I can scale the model (by modifying a 3D gameObject's components) but it doesn't run animations now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set correct basic scale in imported model:
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7G1l.jpg
2. Create 2 objects on the scene.
3. Set scale of every single object to needed inside of "transform" component
4. Create prefabs Elf0.4 and Elf0.25 from created objects
5. delete from scene those objects.
6. use those prefabs on the needed scenes.